# Spark explode function is not responding on large data

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

In my spark job Dataset i have 7.5 million records and one of the column which is type of List and probably size of this list is 100-150.

```
select explode(listOfString),IMSI,IMEI from temp
```

so i did explode on `listOfString` column by spark explode function but my job is **stuck 12 hours**. so what should i do.